# Functions inside setInterval in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have a problem to call functions inside the setInterval function in JavaScript.
My code:

```
setInterval(function() {
y.on('deviceconnected', function(device) {
    console.log("Power off the device");

    var state = false;
    y.setPower(device, state, 300);
});
}, 3000);
```

That function powers off my room bulb and it works fine out of the setInterval. 
Unfortunately, inside the setInterval it doesn't work at all. Program never enters the function and for example print: Power off the device.

How should I call that functions inside the setInterval?

Comment: Unrelated, but you're adding a new handler every three seconds.

Comment: looks like you are working with USB API in JavaScript ???

Comment: Why do you need the `setInterval` on this example anyway? Seems redundant to set the same handler over and over and over again.

Comment: Why should you need to attach a handler every three seconds?

Comment: Try this: https://repl.it/repls/HonorableDeliciousVerification

Comment: If it works fine without the first+last lines, what more do you expect from the variant with `setInterval()`?

Comment: Inside the setInterval function I read lux value from my light sensor which is in my room using request to my server. I want to steer my room bulb using Lux value from my light sensor. Steering means Power on, set brightness etc. But functions which powers on, set brightness doesn't work inside setInterval function but out of that it works. I wonder how to make it working

Comment: I am using setInterval because I want to steer my bulb completely automatically 
in real time

Comment: *set brightness doesn't work inside `setInterval` function but out of that it works*, then don't put it inside `setInterval`. What's the problem that you need to put it inside `setInterval`? I don't really know if `setInterval` has anything to do with "real time"?

Comment: @LoiNguyenHuynh because I want to steer my room bulb in real time for the whole life of the program

Comment: The `setInterval` is completely redundant, as pointed out many times. It does not add any "real time" properties to the program. You should refresh your understanding of event handlers.

Comment: Okay I use node-yeelight library and there have to be y.listen(); inside the setInterval function

Comment: @Roope now I understand your point of view. I should setInterval only in the function which takes Lux value from the server. Outside should be the bulb control service?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it backwards compared to what is needed. Yes, [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-yeelight) write

> Before attempting to control any devices you must have completed device discovery and connection.

but it means that it has to happen before controlling, once. Not once every 3 seconds.
You would need the complete opposite:

```
...
y.on('deviceconnected', function(device) {
  y.setPower(device,true,300);
  setInterval(function(){
    y.setBrightness(device,50,300);
    setTimout(function(){
      y.setBrightness(device,100,300);
    },1500);
  },3000);
});
```

Totally ad-hoc example, copied the pieces from docs. 300-s are transition times (in ms), first it powers up the device, then it tries to toggle between 50% and 100% brightness at every 1.5 seconds (more-or-less, that inner timeout is not very nice, it could rather use a state variable instead).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that I didnt mantioned but I have function which search the network looking for my device and function which connect my client to the device. Moreover, I have function which takes lux value from my light sensor, using request to my server. Using that value, I want to steer my room bulb in Real Time. By that, I mean running client which use power and brigthness functions which will steer my room bulb (that algorytm isnt done yet) . I thought that setInterval Will be Best for that purpose but I am open to other solutions. Thanks for the help